# Create my own Slider for multitouch application

Tags: wpf, slider, touch, multi-touch

The Slider control in WPF doesn't work properly for what I'm looking for.

I need to slide 2 different controls (Slider) at the same time (with one finger each).
When I touch the first Slider, it gets all the focus and I cannot touch anything else with my second touch device.

So I need to create my own Slider (MySlider) that inherit from Slider.
I've made 4 methods:

```
protected override void OnTouchDown(TouchEventArgs e)
protected override void OnTouchUp(TouchEventArgs e)
protected override void OnTouchLeave(TouchEventArgs e)
protected override void OnTouchMove(TouchEventArgs e)
```

But is there a way to move the Slider exactly like with the mouse? Or I need to calcule each time my touch device moved something like:

```
protected override void OnTouchMove(TouchEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnTouchMove(e);

    if (this.Value <= this.Maximum && this.Value >= this.Minimum)
    {
        Point newPoint = e.GetTouchPoint(this).Position;
        this.Value += (this.lastPoint.Y - newPoint.Y);
        lastPoint = newPoint;
    }  
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

And in this case the movement doesn't move at the same speed as the finger...

Comment: No one can help me with this? To create my own slider for multitouch...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the [Surface 2.0 SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff727815.aspx) as it contains a class called [SurfaceSlider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.surfaceslider.aspx), which I believe will allow for two or more sliders to be updated simultaneously. This SDK can be used to target applications built for Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with multi-touch events in WPF so will not be able to help you with that. However, for moving the mouse to the same location as your touching then you can look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902695/how-can-i-show-a-vertical-line-on-mouse-over/8903110#8903110).

Your problem that you're assuming that the width of the control is equivalent to the maximum value. You need to take out the factor the actual width relative to the difference between the max and min values.

This can only be done via events since no routed event or DPs for mouse position.